# web.config debug/release not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, web-config, release

in my web.config

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="Context" connectionString="Server=tcp:database.windows.net,1433;Database=DbDev;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx.;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<connectionStrings/>
```

my web.Debug.config

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

    <connectionStrings>

      <add name="Context" connectionString="Server=tcp:database.windows.net;Database=DbDev;
      User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx.;
      Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>

      <customErrors mode="Off" xdt:Transform="Replace">

      </customErrors>

    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

in my web.Release.config

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

    <connectionStrings>

      <add name="Context" connectionString="Server=tcp:database.windows.net;
           Database=DbProd;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx.;
           Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
            xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />

      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm" mode="On" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>

    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

it's just not getting the production database DbProd

Comment: What's not working, exactly?  What's the symptom you're experiencing?

Comment: so the website is not getting the production database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think when running 'release' mode in VS, it will transform the web.release.config file, but it won't use it due to some reasons ( cache? bin?).However, when I publish it in the Azure environment, then it will get the config correctly

Comment: Same for me.  Switched to "Release" locally and it didn't switch out my connection strings, but once I published to Azure it worked.

Comment: Also you can read this and will understand that this transform works only when publish https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415614/web-config-build-vs-release-transform-not-working

Answer (score 1):

`xdt:Locator="Match(name)"` means transformed values will be applied if `name` attribute values match.

In web.config you have

```
<add name="Context"
```

But in web.release.config

```
<add name="PoqContext"
```

Changing connection string names to same value should help you. Also, take a look at [Web.config Transformation Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx)  for other available options

Comment: sorry, it was typo, the name should be the same