# ASP web.config exclude bin folder on publishing

Tags: asp.net, web-config

It is my first experience with asp.net. I have some large dll in my bin that never change and I would like to exclude them from publishing every time I make small changes to the pages. I know I need to add a section in my web.config but I do not know where and what to write in it to exclude the bin folder.
I already looked at few similar question on SO but none of them are really giving a clear answer to my need.
[This](http://pastebin.com/6xSuAiGm) is my web.config in which I have already added successfully the connection string for the production server and the error mode to have some feedback about errors during deployement phase.
Few lines of code to direct me on what to change will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any updates on this? I also wanted to exclude the bin folder on publishing.

Answer (score -2):

To exclude any file from being copied; you can control this behavior by adding that file to your project; Once you add that file, you will see it in your Solution Explorer Right click on file and choose Properties . On the property page there is a Property called 'Copy to Output Directory' use that.

Comment: That does not work for dll files in the bin of a asp web project!

Comment: Are those dll files added to your project as an item and their Build Action is None and CopyToOutputDIrectory is Do Not Copy ?

Comment: As I already said, what you have in mind is not an option. In this case something along these lines is needed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415614/web-config-build-vs-release-transform-not-working