# .NET Entity Framework worked in VS debug but failed to connect to database in running

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple Web API using .net Entity Framework Core 2.2. Everything works in debug mode in Visual Studio. But when I build and run it, it fails to connect to the database.

The error massage :

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>   Connection id "0HLRCVL1R3B1L", Request id "0HLRCVL1R3B1L:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: connectionString
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
>   at TSPfizer.CentoMiner.Web.Startup.b__4_1(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in C:\Users\shangl02\source\repos\TSolution\CentoMinerWebAPI\Startup.cs:line 43

Did I miss something there?

Comment: The compiler may be changing the connection string in release mode. I would check the config.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415614/web-config-build-vs-release-transform-not-working/25301705#25301705

Comment: Check your appsettings. The Release settings might contain empty connection string. Another option, do the `IConfiguration.GetConnectionString("name")` at runtime and check what you get in both Debug and Release.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is the release setting removed the connection string.